# Why is django.conf.urls.static.static returning an empty list?

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to allow serving files from my media directory, but the media url isn't getting included... here's my code:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [ ... ]
if settings.LOCALHOST_DEVELOPMENT:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

From a Django shell session:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.LOCALHOST_DEVELOPMENT
True
>>> settings.MEDIA_URL
'/media/'
>>> settings.MEDIA_ROOT
'/Users/[my username]/code/survey_server/media'
>>> from survey_server import urls
```

That last call return a list of urls without media url...

```
>>> from django.conf.urls.static import static
>>> static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
[]
```

... and it looks like the media url wasn't included because that static call is returning an empty list. Why is this empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `DEBUG = True` in my settings.py file got this working.

Here's what the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#static) for this function says (emphasis added):

Helper function to return a URL pattern for serving files **in debug mode**